# Splitting and printing with Perl

Tags: perl, printing

My Perl script is attempting to take in a command line argument that is  a file name such as name.txt or hello.txt.exe and parse out the file extension based on the . delimiter, and print only the extension like exe or txt. Here's what I currently have which doesn't print anything and I'm not entirely sure why.

```
usr/bin/perl -w
use  strict;

my ($user_arg) = shift @ARGV;

my ($ext); 

if ( ($ext) = $user_arg =~ /(\.[^.].+)$/) 
{

    print "Ends in ", ($ext) = $user_arg =~ /(\.[^.].+)$/ , "\n";
    print "Ends in" , ($ext) = $user_arg =~ /(\.[^.]+)$/, "\n";


}
elsif( ($ext) = $user_arg =~ /(\.[^.]+)$/)
{ 
    print"Ends in " , ($ext), "\n";

}
else
{
    print "No Extension";

}
```

*Updated, now my problem is the first statement will print both conditions if it's something like name.txt it will print .txt twice, where I want it to only print .txt once UNLESS it's name.txt.exe where I'd like it to print .txt.exe then .exe

Comment: you need to unpack ARGV most likely your just getting the length. `my ($user_arg) = @ARGV;`

Comment: I added the parentheses and nothing changed.

Comment: @JohnnyDiamond08 that's because your `split` is wrong.

Comment: @JohnnyDiamond08 updated my answer to give you more than enough to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two main issues here:

1) You need to `shift` off `@ARGV`

```
my $arg = shift @ARGV;
```

2) You need to escape the 'dot'

```
my @values = split /\./, $user_arg;
```

Other things...

You usually want to sanitize user input:

```
 die "usage: $0 filename\n" if {some condition}
```

I think you mean `chomp $val;` in your `foreach`.

It wouldn't hurt to be familiar with [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html), `fileparse` could make your life easier. Although it might be overkill here.

**UPDATE**

You should be able to integrate this yourself. In your case you won't need to loop
over a list of files, you'll just have one.

This doesn't do what you want where it prints "txt.exe", "exe". But you can fine tune this to your liking.

```
my @file_tests = qw(nosuffix testfile.txt /path/to/file.exe foo.bar.baz);

for my $fullname (@file_tests) {

    my @names = split /\./, $fullname;
    # shift off the first element, which will
    # give you the list of suffixs or an empty list
    shift @names;

    # you can decide how you want to print this list
    # if scalar @names is 0 don't print anything
    print "list of suffixes: " . join( ', ', @names ) . "\n"
        if scalar(@names) > 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
list of suffixes: txt
list of suffixes: exe
list of suffixes: bar, baz
```